# When will fsck run if maximum mount count is -1?

Tags: linux, fsck, ext

I am trying to determine if `fsck` will run on reboot. I run this command `dumpe2fs -h /dev/(diskname)` and get this result:

```
Mount count:              13
Maximum mount count:      -1
```

AFAIK `fsck` will run if mount count is equal or greater than maximum mount count. In this case maximum mount count is -1 so `fsck` will never run. Is this normal?

Answer (score 7):

From [`man tune2fs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)

> `-c max-mount-counts`
>
> Adjust the number of mounts after which the filesystem will be checked by `e2fsck(8)`. If max-mount-counts is `0` or `-1`, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by `e2fsck(8)` and the kernel.

In this case "disregarded" means that yes, `fsck` will never run for this reason and this is normal. However there is also

> `-i interval-between-checks[d|m|w]`
>
> Adjust the maximal time between two filesystem checks. No suffix or `d` will interpret the number interval-between-checks as days, `m` as months, and `w` as weeks. A value of zero will disable the time-dependent checking.

So `fsck` may still run for this other reason, depending on whether or not the interval is set.

> It is strongly recommended that either `-c` (mount-count-dependent) or `-i` (time-dependent) checking be enabled to force periodic full `e2fsck(8)` checking of the filesystem. Failure to do so may lead to filesystem corruption (due to bad disks, cables, memory, or kernel bugs) going unnoticed, ultimately resulting in data loss or corruption.

Comment: I checked it again and my `Check interval` is 0. What you say is a good number for max mount count?

Comment: @IMB I guess it depends on how you use the filesystem, how often you restart etc. But really I can't give you a good advice because I widely use `btrfs`, not `ext`.

Comment: I use it as server for multiple websites. I rarely restart, maybe once or twice a year

Comment: @IMB I think you should ask a separate question about reasonable numbers for `tune2fs`, then somebody else may help you. Check if [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) is a better place for this second question since you're trying to tweak a server (I don't say it is, I say check).